# Why is my body shaking during certain exercises?

Tags: workout

During *some* exercises (push-ups, crunshes) my whole body shakes, I feel a tremor that I cannot control. This happens even during first push-up, when I'm not tired at at all. So, my questions are:

1. What could be a reason for this?
2. Does this tremor affect the efficiency of my workout?
3. Should I be trying to control it, and if yes, how?

I'm 37, and started working out recently after a long period without any physical activity.

Comment: Do you feel tremmors as well when doing modified pushups with your knees down?

Comment: @RobinAshe: Yes, even when doing the "easy" ones (just tried). Although I feel the shaking more in my upper arms and not in the abs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an article from LiveStrong.com about muscle tremors: http://www.livestrong.com/article/446452-tremors-while-exercising/

Basically, without a proper medical examination, there is no way to tell if the cause is just lack of fitness or nutrition or something else.  SO, step one: get a complete physical, step two find a local personal trainer to make sure you have a good/proper workout routine and associate diet.

You can 'work through' or force yourself to continue, but this could lead to further issues - so, take a step back, your body is telling you something and you need a professional medical person to help understand what it's saying.  I'm sure its nothing more than your current condition and diet.

Answer (score 2):

The uber physical therapy expert Mike Reinold in his sport coach's seminars tells them they can only rule things *in* - only a doctor with the right equipment can rule something out. so I agree with @Meade while at the same time who can afford a real check-up? I don't like the sound of "my whole body" shaking. When I do weighted push ups with my feet elevated on a bench, my hips will shake just before failure on my heavy sets because the small synergist muscles are giving out. I know these are weak because I can't do hip airplanes very well despite my squatting strength. That doesn't sound like what's happening to you, unless all your synergists are weak. You might try backing off completely and looking for extremely wussy exercises (wall push ups) and see if that helps, but of course now we're playing doctor ruling out god knows what.

Answer (score 1):

While workout your body shakes,it has two reasons.First is that may your body shaking means you are working and strengthening your muscle.Second is the negative point it must be due to the weakness and deficiency of vitamins or water in your body.If your doing some exercise to the first time like stretching and strengthening then it was sure that your body will shake.But if the muscle starts shaking in the beginning of the exercise then it is a warning that the exercise is too difficult for your body to handle.There are things that effect accordingly so you have to prepare yourself for the effects of exercise in your body.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for your tremor, ranging from Parkinson's (for which you, according to incidence statistics, are too young) and cerebellar ataxia (unlikely without other neurological deficits or a previous history of trauma) to benign muscular apraxia. The only way to know would be to perform a physical examination.

You say that your whole body shakes, and that is, in its literal sense, a neurological symptom. However, seeing that you just started working out after a long period without physical activity, the most likely etiology is that you have poor inter- and intramuscular coordination.

Basically, your brain and muscles aren't used to performing those movements smoothly and efficiently. This always happens during the initial phases of training, even for experienced athletes after years of training with a short detraining period, but also when doing a new exercise.

In case your tremor does not subside within the next 5-6 training sessions, or at least improve, then it is likely something else. If it does, then you have nothing to worry about, there is no need to control it, and it will go away on its own once you get more used to performing those movements.