# plank shakes - what does it mean?

Tags: core

I have been doing plank hold in good form since atleast 2-3 months. I get shakey after 10 seconds even though I can hold it between 60-75 seconds. I don't see any improvement in shakiness.

What does it mean? Is it Weak core?

Comment: Generally it's a weakness thing. If you're not already doing compound barbell work (deads/squats/ohp/cleans) consider starting. Front squats in particular require a lot of abdominal strength.

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons you start shaking when performing an exercise.

1. Imbalance of power.
2. Not enough muscle power.
3. Fatigue.
4. Lack of oxygen to the muscles.

[Read more](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/13389/8606)